# TabActivity и ViewPager

Tags: android, activity, android-viewpager

Какие различии между TabActivity и ViewPager? и где лучше всего их использовать?

Comment: `TabActivity` объявлена устаревшей еще с API13. В наше время ее лучше всего вообще не использовать

Comment: окей, то есть щас лучше всего использовать viewPager? или он на что то другое заменен?

Comment: @PaNDa11v48, это совершенно разные вещи. Табы не обязательно используются с ViewPager, а ViewPager можно делать без табов. Всё зависит от вашей задачи. И табы теперь следует через TabLayout делать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Различие между ними в том, что они выполняют разные функции:)

> Tablayout обеспечивает горизонтальное расположение для отображения
>   вкладок, которые позволяют переключаться между различными фрагментами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так выглядит типичный пример TabLayout. Как говорилось выше, стоит забыть о TabActivity и использовать только TabLayout.

> ViewPager это Layout с возможностью прокрутки и автодоводкой. Аналогию
>   можно привести с книгой. Страницу можно перелистнуть вперед или назад
>   и на каждой странице свое содержимое. Как и у книги, viewPager имеет
>   начальный и конечный лист. Сами листы представляются Fragment. Для
>   использования необходимо написать адаптер. Наследуемый, например, от
>   FragmentPagerAdapter или StateFragmentPagerAdapter. Подробнее об этом
>   можно найти в интернете

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример viewPager